# How to change Java JVM for JBoss?

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jvm

I did an installation on my Mac of a new Java SDK (1.6 -> 1.7).

On command line it shows the 1.7. And I even changed the Mac's Symlink of CurrentJDK.

But JBoss still shows me a path entry "java.home" pointing to 1.6. And it is not possible to change that via admin website.

Anybody know how to change that?

PS: I start JBoss from Eclipse, which knows also 1.7 now as default.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Launch Configuration for your JBoss server in Eclipse. On the **JRE** tab you can select the specific Java runtime that it will run in. If the option *Project Execution Environment* is selected (the default), then you can change it by opening the Project properties, going to the **Java Build Path** section, then the **Libraries** tab. Select the *JRE System Library* entry from the **Libraries** list then use the **Edit...* button to select your desired Execution Environment.

Comment: I found it ... it was a bit different ... but thanks anyway.

Eclipse:

Preferences and seach for "runtime environment". There it is possible to edit the server and change the JVM.

Comment: Going back to at least the Helios release the provided answer here is correct. Note that correct answers will never get any more correct than exactly correct. This answer is helpful because as well as being correct, it is explained well and fully. @Andreas found a different route to the same setting yet he didn't wish to write up his own answer.